# C# Timespan in hh:mm:ss With Days Included In Hours

Tags: c#

I have a sample `TimeSpan` object like this:

```
{9.04:00:00}
    Days: 9
    Hours: 4
    Milliseconds: 0
    Minutes: 0
    Seconds: 0
    Ticks: 7920000000000
    TotalDays: 9.1666666666666661
    TotalHours: 220
    TotalMilliseconds: 792000000
    TotalMinutes: 13200
    TotalSeconds: 792000
```

When I run `.ToString()` on it, it is returned in this format: `"9.04:00:00"`. However, I would like to have it in hh:mm:ss format only.

The expected output should be `"220:00:00"`. How would I achieve that?

Comment: you can pass format, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-7.0

Comment: I know I can pass the format but still not able to get days into hours + actual hours

Comment: you can use TicksPerDay to get days into hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a way to do what you want directly.`TimeSpan` format strings don't support that.

You could write a customer [`IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=net-7.0) and the corresponding [`ICustomFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icustomformatter?view=net-7.0)

[Doing it right is more difficult than you might think.]
.
.
.
Or you could just write a simple extension method along these lines:

```
using System;

namespace Example
{
  public class Program
  {
    
    public static void Main()
    {
      TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1,2,3,4,5); // 1d2h3m4s5ms
      Console.WriteLine( ts.ToHMS() );
    }
  
  }
  
  public static class TimeSpanExtensions
  {
    
    public static string ToHMS( this TimeSpan ts )
    {
      bool isNegative = false;
      if ( ts < TimeSpan.Zero )
      {
          isNegative = true ;
          ts = ts.Duration();
      }
      long hh  = 24 * ts.Days + ts.Hours;
      int  mm  = ts.Minutes;
      int  ss  = ts.Seconds;
        
      string fmt = isNegative
                 ? "-{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}"
                 :  "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}"
                 ;
      
      string s = string.Format( fmt, hh, mm, ss );
      return s;     
    }
    
  }

}
```

If you need to support localization, though, the custom formatter is probably where you need to go.

Comment: Does this work with negative TimeSpans as well?

Comment: Sample expected output -240:04:00

Comment: It does now. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with format strings. They don't support triple digit hours.  You'll have to write a method.

```
public static string ToHourString(this TimeSpan t) =>
    $"{(t.TotalHours >= 1 ? t.TotalHours : 0):00}:{t:mm\\:ss}";
```

Output of `TimeSpan.FromHours(220).ToHourString()`:

```
220:00:00
```

Output of `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(44).ToHourString()`:

```
0:44:00
```

(Thanks Tom!)

Comment: Works great but small bug if TotalHours is single digit

Comment: Oh nice catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Is it possible to get `0:44:00` to be `00:44:00`? I need each of them to be at least two digits with the exception of hours being able to have more than two digits

Comment: Yes, I made another edit that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thouse examples:

```
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(9, 4, 0, 0);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes,ts.Seconds));
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                                       (int)ts.TotalHours,
                                       ts.Minutes,
                                       ts.Seconds));
```

First example:

[image]

Second:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got another way of doing it with the help of Victor's answer:

```
public static string ToHourFormat(this TimeSpan @this)
{
    string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        @this.Hours + @this.Days * 24,
        @this.Minutes,
        @this.Seconds);

    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function for returning a `TimeSpan`, returning a string with the `TimeSpan` formatted in hh:mm:ss. Bool is optional (to clarify).

```
private string getTime(TimeSpan ts, bool secondZero = true)
    {
        if (!secondZero)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        }
    }
```